# Heroku App Crashing with Syntax Error for Hoek

Tags: node.js, heroku, slack-api

I'm trying to build the Slack app found here: https://github.com/shaykalyan/slack-ascii

It builds successfully, but gives this output when I try to run it:

```
2018-02-14T16:21:18.323723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`

2018-02-14T16:21:20.151317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2018-02-14T16:21:20.137708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085005+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js:5

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085023+00:00 app[web.1]: const Hoek = require('hoek');

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085025+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085027+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085028+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085030+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085032+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085034+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085035+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085037+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085038+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:384:17)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085040+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/index.js:5:33)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085042+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)

2018-02-14T16:21:20.085043+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Comment: Can you improve the formatting?

Comment: Looks like it is already